# Gradle uploadArtifacts Fails When Specifying Group Property

Tags: java, continuous-integration, gradle, nexus

I'm trying to do a gradle uploadArtifacts to upload to my nexus server and it works when my build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
version = "1.0"
uploadArchives {
    repositories { ivy { url "http://<server>/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots" } }
}
```

However, if I specify a group to upload to, e.g. if I change my build.gradle to:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
group = "test"      // <-- addition of group property
version = "1.0"
uploadArchives {
    repositories { ivy { url "http://<server>/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots" } }
}
```

It fails saying:

```
Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > java.io.IOException: Could not PUT 'http://<server>/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/test/test-project/1.0/test-project-1.0.jar'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
```

If I run with --debug the exception that I'm getting is:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not PUT 'http://<server>/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/test/test-project/1.0/test-project-1.0.jar'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
```

I thought it might be a problem creating the directories on the server since this is a new artifact, but even if I manually create test/test-project/1.0, the upload still fails.  (It doesn't fail without the group ID though which leads me to believe it's not a nexus problem).

My Setup is:

Gradle 1.5
Gradle build time: Wednesday, March 27, 2013 1:51:06 PM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.6.0_43 (Apple Inc. 20.14-b01-447)
OS: Mac OS X 10.7.5 x86_64

and

Sonatype Nexus™ 2.3.0-04

Has anyone seen this before or know what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know gradle at all, but it seems like you are trying to publish a non-snapshot artifact to a snapshot repository:

```
version = "1.0"
url "http://<server>/nexus/content/repositories/*snapshots*"
```

You can also see that in the final URL:
`http://<server>/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/test/test-project/1.0/test-project-1.0.jar`

Comment: hmm.. you're on to something.  if i change the version to 1.0-SNAPSHOT it uploaded with the group id. that's really confusing.  so with a group id i can only upload version 1.0-SNAPSHOT and without a group id I can upload 1.0-SNAPSHOT or 1.0.  any clue why that would be?

Comment: My guess is that if you omit the group id, you circumvent the checks in Nexus that would reject your artifact based on the repository policy, because no group id is not valid for maven artifacts ("groupId will identify your project uniquely across all projects", http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html, or "groupId: This is generally unique amongst an organization or a project.", http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates)

Comment: thanks!  that explains it enough for me.  now off to learn more about gradle.  :)